# How to change UI Slider's physical location using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I am trying to change the position of the jquery slider by pressing the button "POSITIONSLIDERTOZERO".
This sets the new position variable to 0.
It also sets the value to 0 but the actual slider does not move to position 0. It stays where it was set before.

I had a look at this fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/C8X4D/

This is pretty similar to what i am trying to achieve except it is using text box.

Here is my code:
& JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ns7sq02n/3/

```
  function initSlider() {
        $(slider).slider({
                    max: 100,
                    min: 0,
                    step: 1,
                    value: 0,
                    animate: true,
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        $(slider + "NewPosition").text("New Position : " + ui.value);
                        newPosition = ui.value;
                    }
                });

    }

$(slider + 'POSITIONSLIDERTOZERO').on("click", function () {
 $(slider + "NewPosition").text("New Position : " + 0);
$(slider + 'POSITIONSLIDERTOZERO').slider('value',0);
}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of your code? It is hard to say something without knowing the html part of your code.

Comment: I am doing that right now. Thank you :)

Comment: All done on jsfiddle.

Comment: All done on jsfiddle. If you change the slider and click gohome, the position resets to 0 but the slider is still at the previous position.

Answer (score 0):

Had to set the slider value to 0

```
$("#POSITIONSLIDERTOZERO").on("click", function() {
  $("#home" + "NewPosition").text("New Position : " + 0);
  $("#home").slider('value', 0);
});
```

Full working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ns7sq02n/6/